# Android app for GPS project

Tags: java, android, gps, arduino, raspberry-pi

I decided to do a GPS car tracker for my college project and I need a bit of guidance on the actual framework for it.
My main plan is to use either an arduino (or raspberry pi) with a GPS and 3G module attached which would would alert  the accompanying android app if the module was moved out of a certain location(if car is taken without permission etc).The app could also be used to request the location at will from the module.
My question is 
Is this possible for me to achieve and would I be better using an arduino or raspberry pi,would I have more freedom with the pi as maybe I could run a service on it??
It would be great to get some opinions from anyone
Thanks

Comment: http://www.raspberrypi.org/ Try searching here and SE also has a raspberry pi fourm.  Check the links in the footer down below. Click "more" in the second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very possible and has already been done. It is also possible to use the two together to achieve this, but if you had to choose one, I would choose the RPi. This is because it can do more of what your are attempting straight out of the box with its full linux capabilities (wireless, etc). This can come ready to go if you get a preloaded SD card. Search for a NOOBS SD card on amazon.

Comment: What do you mean wireless capabilities? It doesn't have  GPS or 3G as standard does it??

Comment: Thanks for these I will do some more research on both but I think the pi may be a bit easier to work with yes?

Comment: 100% yes the pi just like a baby computer.

Comment: Can I run apache server on the pi and use the android app to request the geolocations and other info through http requests??

Comment: You can definitely run Apache on the pi. Let's put it this way...Anything you can do on a regular machine running linux - you can pretty much do on a pi.